# libGDX- where is jogl package?

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

Going thru this tutorial
http://www.playandroid.com/blog/a-review-of-libgdx-cross-platform-library-for-games-development/

and have downloaded the source files for 0.9.9 libGDX here
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html

For some reason the jogl (com.badlogic.backends.jogl.*) package is missing.

Its not here either
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends

Can any libGDX gurus help?

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted a wrong answer based on an old quote written with an old version of JOGL in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Libgdx has seen some major changes in the last year. A complete 3D Api rewrite, Switch to Robovm and Deprecating Xamarin for iOS. and of course the Jogl backend deprecation is one of them. [Jogl Backend Deprecation](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2566)

> It’s been lurking in the air for quite a while now, but i will
>   deprecate the Jogl backend this week. The Lwjgl backend is a lot more
>   functional and stable, and actually easier to integrate in SWT or
>   Swing apps via LwjglAWTCanvas. You can even add multiple canvas
>   widgets that share the same context.

Many tutorials out there are outdated.

I recommend you to check the [Official Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki) for the most updated information about libgdx.

Comment: Sorry but despite the deprecation, our JOGL backend works very well. The quote is wrong. JOGL has the best AWT, Swing and SWT integration since its second version, this sentence is old, it was written with JOGL 1 in mind whereas in JOGL 2, there are an heavyweight canvas supporting SWT and a lightweight one too. You quote a sentence written in 2012 whereas Mario didn't even know JOGL 2 despite its development since 2010...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* use JOGL 2 with libgdx - mainly because of the efforts of JOGL crew; see [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/JOGL-2-0-OpenGL-OpenGL-ES-backend-for-LibGDX-td4027689.html) for details. It's semi-actively developed, with newest updates dating to 2014 *as of 2014*...

Comment: Good catch :) xranby's code might be a bit more up to date than mine: https://github.com/xranby/libgdx However, we don't use JOGL 2 under Android yet. I plan to use JOGL 2 under Android only within JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation for the moment. eco_bach, Xerxes or me, one of us will check that it still works correctly and will update it. We were forced to modify a bit the core, it drives the updates a bit tricky :s

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libGDX setup tool. You just need to run the packaged file called

```
gdx-setup-ui.jar
```

Go though the steps to create a new project with all the dependencies already configured. You can find a detailed tutorial at the [libGDX wiki on github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup,-running-&-debugging).

Comment: Though good and valid information in your answer. This doesn't really answer the OP question.